# error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name when running in Chrome

Tags: asp.net

I am getting "error on line 1 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name" when I try to run my ASP.Net page in Chrome or Edge.  The page runs fine from Visual Studio and I have checked everything in IIS that the answers here have said to check.  This is the line that is giving me the error:

```
<%@ Page Title="Risk Calculator" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicMenu2._Default" %>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Donald

Comment: I have also published this to a folder on my computer and tried running it from there.

Comment: I forgot to mention my Windows version.  We are using Windows 10 Enterprise at work.

Comment: this is what my Web.config file looks like:  '<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization.WebForms" tagPrefix="webopt"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>'